# Possible to use timeout in WWW::Mechanize on https?

Tags: perl, https, timeout, mechanize, www-mechanize

We have a Perl script which uses [WWW::Mechanize](http://search.cpan.org/~jesse/WWW-Mechanize-1.72/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm) to download content from a secured (https) website via our company proxy using POST action in WWW::Mechanize.

Sometimes this post action runs for hours for unknown reasons.

I want to control this. I checked for timeout but I also read in one of the post in Stackoverflow that it does not work with https websites.

Any idea how I can use the timeout mechanism?

I want to stop processing that link say after a minute or so to proceed further and not wait for hours together. Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Use [LWPx::ParanoidAgent](http://p3rl.org/LWPx::ParanoidAgent) and mix it into Mech.

> ```
> $ua->timeout(10);
> ```
>
> this is 10 seconds overall, from start to finish.  not just between
> socket reads.  and it includes all redirects.  so attackers telling
> you to download from a malicious tarpit webserver can only stall
> you for $n seconds